# List files in a directory with a certain extension

Tags: shell, wildcards

I created a file called `~/usrlibs.txt`, which contains the number of files that begin with `lib` and end `.a` found in the `/usr/lib directory`.

I tried:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/lib .a | wc -w > ~/usrlibs.txt
```

But this command is not working correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I assume that is a typo: `ls -l /usr/lib/lib .a` should be `ls -l /usr/lib/lib*.a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean list all files that start with `lib` and end with `.a` in `/usr/lib`, then print the wordcount with `wc` to `usrlibs.txt`?

```
ls -l /usr/lib/lib*.a | wc -w > ~/usrlibs.txt
```

should work. You just forgot to add a wildcard between your patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Your command `ls -l /usr/lib/lib*.a | wc -w > ~/usrlibs.txt` just counts the words of the output that `ls -l` generates.

I think what you search counting the word in those `lib*.a` files:

```
user@host:~# wc -w /usr/lib/lib*.a
    222 /usr/lib/libanl.a
     31 /usr/lib/libBrokenLocale.a
     24 /usr/lib/libbsd-compat.a
  54564 /usr/lib/libc.a
    298 /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a
    832 /usr/lib/libcrypt.a
    206 /usr/lib/libdl.a
     24 /usr/lib/libg.a
      6 /usr/lib/libieee.a
  15842 /usr/lib/libm.a
     12 /usr/lib/libmcheck.a
   2681 /usr/lib/libnsl.a
  37214 /usr/lib/libpthread.a
     99 /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
   1537 /usr/lib/libresolv.a
    600 /usr/lib/librpcsvc.a
    984 /usr/lib/librt.a
    431 /usr/lib/libsupp.a
    164 /usr/lib/libutil.a
 115771 total
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'find' instead of 'ls':

```
find /usr/lib -name "lib*.a" | wc -w > ~/usrlibs.txt
```

The wildcard: * in the phrase "lib*.a" will give you all files that start with 'lib' and end with '.a'